# Set nested property value and create parent if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-2

So I am using Ember JS 2.2 and I have a plain JS object and want to set the value of a nested property. However I don't know if some of the parent properties already exist. If they don't exist I would like to create them as an empty object. Basically I would like to do this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
let myObj = {};
Ember.set(myObj, 'first_level.second_level.third_level', 'the value I want to set');
```

and it look like:

```
{
 "first_level":
  {
    "second_level":
      {
       "third_level":"the value I want to set"
      }
  }
}
```

I know I could check each level manually and assign it if it doesn't exist but I was hoping Ember has something baked in that can do this. I *thought* I read that there was an existing way to do this in Ember but can't seem to find it in the docs. Could anyone tell me if I am missing something or will I just have to write my own implementation? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have to implement it yourself, Ember.js does not have an API to do it.

Comment: You can use lodash. It set method should do what u need.